# Practicing electric guitar using a Boss Katana, what can I use for playing backing tracks?

Tags: electric-guitar

I've been practicing electric guitar using a Katana for the past few months, I was considering playing over a track, but not sure how to do it.

I don't think the Katana can play anything other than what I connect to it, as in a laptop through USB, quick google searches seems to indicate that, but correct me if I'm wrong.

I do have some decent headphones, Sennheiser HD600, but I don't have speakers, could I maybe hook them up to a laptop and set the volume appropriately so I can hear the Katana plus the headphones backing track? does that make sense or what do you guys normally use for this?.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Perhaps I'm being dense, but: "I don't think the Katana can play anything other than what I connect to it"—how could it possibly play something without a connection? If you mean, for example, could you store data within the amp somehow, no, pretty sure it's just an amp. Though 2) could you specify which Katana model? It might have different inputs. And do you have any other speaker of respectable size of any kind? I'm wondering why the track can't just play out loud, without headphones, without interacting with the amp.

Comment: Also, it looks to me like most Katana models have an "aux in" stereo mini jack. If you can connect a CD player or other device via analog stereo plug, you should be able to mix it with your guitar and output both.

Comment: I meant, that I can't for example connect it a USB to the laptop and play a backing track plus my guitar.

Comment: No, I dont have any decent speaker, so before buying one I was curious what's a good method.

Comment: Can you update your question with the specific model of amplifier and a link to the appropriate page at Boss/Roland with the specs?  This may have a very simple answer.

Comment: I just got the Artist mkII and you can do like we did in the old days and play along with your CD player blasting. What I did do is I got a Boss js-10 eBand and this thing is sick. If I had one of those back when I was just starting out I’d probably been a world class guitarist. The are an amazing learning tool and fun as hell. It comes with effects and it has backing tracks pre loaded but you can go to the boss eBand site and download tones and sounds others have downloaded. Also you can also. Download your favorite songs to learn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Katana series has an aux input on the back panel of the amp. This will accept any sound source with a stereo mini jack or or mini jack adapter. There is no independent volume control for the aux input so you will have to use the master volume and the guitar channel volume to get the right balance.

The USB connection is only for sending audio from the amp to a computer for recording. It does not accept audio from a computer to play through the amp.

Here is a link to the manual: https://static.roland.com/assets/media/pdf/KTN-Mk2_eng02_W.pdf

Pages 6 and 7 have the info relevant to your question, look at items 20 and 21 below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, basically, connect mini trs jack from headphone socket on computer to port 21?